# Vanity/Clean URL with Two Parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have a .htaccess file that puts /username to profile.php?id=$0

I need the ability to accept two parameters without clashing with the rewrite rule that takes off the .php extension from php files.

**Here is a clear example of what i want:**

/profile.php?id=username&category=schooling **------>** */username/schooling*

I don't want this to affect other php files such as */about*

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\._\-]+)+[^\.php]$ profile.php?id=$0 [NC]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! :)

---

**UPDATE:**

So this worked for me but the images aren't working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\._\-]+)+[^\.php]$ profile.php?id=$0 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1&category=$2 [L]
```

Any ideas? I know the reason behind it but don't know how to fix it. The images urls are also being redirected i think.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original question and provided an update of what worked for me. In that update everything works, even if it makes no sense but the images on the website are not showing. I think they are being treated as profile.php redirects. @zx81

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# IF we have an existing file or folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
# THEN leave the url unchanged, and skip the next two rules
RewriteRule ^ - [L,S=2]
# ELSE (i.e., it's a pretty url that doesn't correspond to a real file or folder)
# Apply these rules if they match
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error on every page including the basic php files such as /about

Comment: Does it have anything to do with me working on a sub-domain? Just wondering , i don't think it would have an affect.

Comment: Well, the `.htaccess` has to be in the right folder. Let's say the file lives in `somefolder`. The url `/somefolder/a/b` will redirect to `somefolder/profile.php?etc` Does that file exist? If not, we'll get a 404. So we either need to fix the path or put the htaccess in the right place.

Comment: I have the .htaccess file in the root of the sub-domain. I've tested it with basic rewrites so I know it works. Very weird

Comment: Can you temporarily change the `L` to `R` in the rules? That way you will be able to see in the browser bar where we're being redirected to, and why that file doesn't exist. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I also added comments inside the answer so you can see how the logic works. Maybe you'll catch something I don't know about that's specific to your site.

Comment: You're welcome. Is the 404 solved? (Did you try the `R` thing I mentioned two comments above?)

Comment: Not yet i'm still experimenting with it. Will let you know once i get it working.

Comment: Alright. The `R` works differently from the `L` in that you can see the place where we redirect in the browser bar, so it's a useful tool for troubleshooting. `404` means the file does not exist, but if we're redirecting to the right `profile.php`, it should exist. The `R` should show us which wrong url exactly we are requesting.

Comment: So i updated the code above still have a slight problem with the images not showing.

Comment: To clarify, you mean you tweaked the code I gave you, or the original one? You should know that the original two-step rule going to ` $1.php` makes no sense at all, even though it may happen to work—please don't use that. It's like saying I want to change A to C, and then saying alright, I'll change it to Z, then I'll change Z to C. With that said, can you tell me what the problem is with the images?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9\._\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ profile.php?id=$1&category=$2 [L, QSA, NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\._\-]+)+[^\.php]$ profile.php?id=$1 [L, QSA, NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1.php [L, QSA]
```

The `L` flag serves to stop mod_rewrite form processing the remaining rules if the rule with `L` is matched.

Comment: This gives me an internal server error on every page including ones that are not rewritten.